# Socket connection to LAN computer fails?

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, connection, httplistener

PC1 and PC2 are connected with a switch.

```
PC1--<-->--SWITCH--<-->--PC2
```

Both have Windows 7 installed.
PC1 has it's firewall on.
PC2 has it's firewall off.
They can share files.
They can remote desktop each other.

There is a HttpListener on PC2 on port 80 but it is not possible to connect from PC1 to PC2 on port 80.
What could be the problem?

**PC1 Network Info:**

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::5948:69a8:d29e:6bfe%11
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.107.254
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

**PC2 Network Info:**

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::5cd8:ed4e:8848:569%11
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.5.105
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

**telnet pc2 80, *from PC1* says:**
Could not open connection to the host, on port 80: Connect failed.

**"netstat -anb" on PC2:**

```
Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    0.0.0.0:80             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  RpcSs
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:445            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    0.0.0.0:554            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 [wmpnetwk.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:2869           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    0.0.0.0:5357           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    0.0.0.0:10243          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49152          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 [wininit.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49153          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  eventlog
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49154          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  Schedule
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49155          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 [services.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49156          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 [lsass.exe]
  TCP    169.254.5.105:139      0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    [::]:80                [::]:0                 LISTENING
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    [::]:135               [::]:0                 LISTENING
  RpcSs
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    [::]:445               [::]:0                 LISTENING
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    [::]:554               [::]:0                 LISTENING
 [wmpnetwk.exe]
  TCP    [::]:2869              [::]:0                 LISTENING
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    [::]:3587              [::]:0                 LISTENING
  p2pimsvc
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    [::]:5357              [::]:0                 LISTENING
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    [::]:10243             [::]:0                 LISTENING
 Can not obtain ownership information
  TCP    [::]:49152             [::]:0                 LISTENING
 [wininit.exe]
  TCP    [::]:49153             [::]:0                 LISTENING
  eventlog
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    [::]:49154             [::]:0                 LISTENING
  Schedule
 [svchost.exe]
  TCP    [::]:49155             [::]:0                 LISTENING
 [services.exe]
  TCP    [::]:49156             [::]:0                 LISTENING
 [lsass.exe]
  TCP    [fe80::5cd8:ed4e:8848:569%11]:445  [fe80::5948:69a8:d29e:6bfe%11]:49569  ESTABLISHED
 Can not obtain ownership information
  UDP    0.0.0.0:68             *:*                    
  Dhcp
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:123            *:*                    
  W32Time
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:3702           *:*                    
  EventSystem
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:3702           *:*                    
  FDResPub
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:3702           *:*                    
  FDResPub
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:3702           *:*                    
  EventSystem
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5004           *:*                    
 [wmpnetwk.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5005           *:*                    
 [wmpnetwk.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:5355           *:*                    
  Dnscache
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:56904          *:*                    
  FDResPub
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:56906          *:*                    
  EventSystem
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    0.0.0.0:65438          *:*                    
  EventSystem
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    127.0.0.1:1900         *:*                    
  SSDPSRV
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    127.0.0.1:56903        *:*                    
  SSDPSRV
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    169.254.5.105:137      *:*                    
 Can not obtain ownership information
  UDP    169.254.5.105:138      *:*                    
 Can not obtain ownership information
  UDP    169.254.5.105:1900     *:*                    
  SSDPSRV
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    169.254.5.105:56902    *:*                    
  SSDPSRV
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    [::]:123               *:*                    
  W32Time
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    [::]:3540              *:*                    
  p2pimsvc
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    [::]:3702              *:*                    
  FDResPub
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    [::]:3702              *:*                    
  EventSystem
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    [::]:3702              *:*                    
  FDResPub
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    [::]:3702              *:*                    
  EventSystem
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    [::]:5004              *:*                    
 [wmpnetwk.exe]
  UDP    [::]:5005              *:*                    
 [wmpnetwk.exe]
  UDP    [::]:5355              *:*                    
  Dnscache
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    [::]:56905             *:*                    
  FDResPub
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    [::]:56907             *:*                    
  EventSystem
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    [::]:65439             *:*                    
  EventSystem
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    [::1]:1900             *:*                    
  SSDPSRV
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    [::1]:56901            *:*                    
  SSDPSRV
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    [fe80::5cd8:ed4e:8848:569%11]:546  *:*                    
  Dhcp
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    [fe80::5cd8:ed4e:8848:569%11]:1900  *:*                    
  SSDPSRV
 [svchost.exe]
  UDP    [fe80::5cd8:ed4e:8848:569%11]:56900  *:*                    
  SSDPSRV
 [svchost.exe]
```

**EDIT1 - Some Wireshark report (telnet pc2 80):**

```
62  28.544466   169.254.5.105   169.254.107.254 NBSS    126 Session request, to PC1<20> from PC2<00>
63  28.544538   169.254.107.254 169.254.5.105   NBSS    58  Positive session response
64  28.544761   169.254.5.105   169.254.107.254 SMB 213 Negotiate Protocol Request
65  28.545154   169.254.107.254 169.254.5.105   SMB2    228 NegotiateProtocol Response
66  28.545359   169.254.5.105   169.254.107.254 SMB2    162 NegotiateProtocol Request
67  28.545527   169.254.107.254 169.254.5.105   SMB2    228 NegotiateProtocol Response
68  28.546260   169.254.5.105   169.254.107.254 SMB2    220 SessionSetup Request, NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE
69  28.546416   169.254.107.254 169.254.5.105   SMB2    339 SessionSetup Response, Error: STATUS_MORE_PROCESSING_REQUIRED, NTLMSSP_CHALLENGE
70  28.546836   169.254.5.105   169.254.107.254 SMB2    294 SessionSetup Request, NTLMSSP_AUTH, User: \, Unknown message type
71  28.547306   169.254.107.254 169.254.5.105   SMB2    159 SessionSetup Response, Unknown message type
72  28.547646   169.254.5.105   169.254.107.254 SMB2    162 TreeConnect Request Tree: \\PC1\IPC$
73  28.547723   169.254.107.254 169.254.5.105   SMB2    138 TreeConnect Response
```

**EDIT2 - Wireshark, Follow TCP Stream:**

```
12  2.197774    fe80::5948:69a8:d29e:6bfe   fe80::5cd8:ed4e:8848:569    TCP 86  50243 > http [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1440 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1
14  5.197056    fe80::5948:69a8:d29e:6bfe   fe80::5cd8:ed4e:8848:569    TCP 86  50243 > http [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1440 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1
19  11.197398   fe80::5948:69a8:d29e:6bfe   fe80::5cd8:ed4e:8848:569    TCP 82  50243 > http [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1440 SACK_PERM=1
```

**SORRY GUYS: The firewall was not completely disabled for private network only public network, i checked again and found out.. Now everything works. Thank you.**

Comment: Can you `telnet localhost 80` on pc2, and can you `ping pc2` from pc1? Seems like this must be a firewall problem to me... and yes, I know you said it was off, but still...

Comment: telnet localhost 80 works not problem,

ping pc2, from pc1 result:

`Pinging PC1 [fe80::5cd8:ed4e:8848:569%11] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from fe80::5cd8:ed4e:8848:569%11: time<1ms
Reply from fe80::5cd8:ed4e:8848:569%11: time<1ms
Reply from fe80::5cd8:ed4e:8848:569%11: time<1ms
Reply from fe80::5cd8:ed4e:8848:569%11: time<1ms

Ping statistics for fe80::5cd8:ed4e:8848:569%11:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms`

Comment: This may be an IPv4 vs IPv6 problem, try connecting explicitly via IPv4 address instead of by NetBIOS name: `telnet 169.254.5.105 80`

Comment: As a side note, you should either set up a DHCP server on the network or statically set your IP addresses (standards dictate that for your setup, you would do this in the 192.168.0.0/16 network, but with a CIDR of 24) - it will make life a lot easier in the long run, and you wont have wait for the machine to negotiate an address layout via ARP everytime you disconnect one of the NICs/reboot one of them.

Comment: telnet 169.254.5.105 80 fails too. I think the same can be IPv4/6 problem. Setting the IP's to be static is after the problem is solved... ;)

Comment: I disabled the IPv6 option on network adapter settings but it didn't work. Telnet still fails.

Comment: Worth a try I suppose, but if specifying the IPv4 address still doesn't work, it's unlikely to make a difference. I think this is a firewall issue somewhere - maybe worth restarting your HTTPListener to get it to re-bind, and try again? Also, if that doesn't work, does it work if you bind to a specific address (i.e. your IPv4 `169...` address)?

Comment: HTTPListener prefix is: http://*:80/
If the connection from local (PC2) it works.
I think the PC2 doesn't even reply to the connection attempt from PC1 according to the wireshark report. This makes the firewall assumption on PC2 to be logical...

Comment: SOLVED. Firewall was not disabled for all networks. (Private, Public)

Comment: Windows 7 strikes again... Probably better to leave it on and explicitly allow your application through it to prevent issues like this (and for better security).

Comment: Yes I'll enable it, thank you for the assisting. That wireshark report and your comments helped me to re-check the firewall. There were 2 options for private (home, work) and public networks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a firewall problem, try to set every firewall including your switch open.

If that solves it, this is no longer a Stack Overflow problem...

Comment: i did "netstat -anb" on PC2 which shows the above result. It shows port 80 is being listened. Which is my HttpListener. Before running the HttpListener net stat didn't give any info about port 80.

Comment: @DaveRandom: No, it's an actual implementation and not pointless. Check the SonicWall Pro 1260, given that such firewall switch exists we can't just ignore the switch. I'd rather think your comment is pointless...

Comment: All firewalls are disabled. If it was a firewall issue the connection would end in a very short time, probably the reply would something like PC2 actively refused the connection or something like that with fast response. But telnet waits some time to reply...

Comment: The switch is just a simple 8 port switch, no firewall. Even if I connect PC1 and PC2 directly via network cable the problem is the same.

Comment: @Samet: Okay. What does Wireshark or a similar tool reveal?

Comment: @Tom that's not really a switch, that's a firewall (like just about everything made by SonicWall) - it just happens to have a switch built in...

Comment: @Samet Just because you are waiting a long time for a response and the connection is not being reset, does not mean you are not being firewalled, many firewalls will silently discard disallowed packets, rather than actively rejecting them. But Tom is bang on in asking about Wireshark, I never develop raw socket apps without it...

Comment: @Samet which firewall(s) have you disabled on PC2? Does it have any 3rd party security software installed or is it all the M$ stuff?

Comment: @Tom Wijsman: Some wireshark report in my edited original message.

Comment: Both of the PCs have fresh windows 7 installed. I disabled windows built-in firewall on pc2. There is no other firewall.

Comment: @Samet that wireshark data does not contain the stream we are discussing here. If you are running on port 80, the traffic we are interested in will show up as 'HTTP' in the 5th column. When you find some, right click on it and click 'Follow TCP Stream', then post that stream here...